# Are there any specific perks for Crafting

Tags: guild-wars-2

Of course I'm going to craft, but I want to limit the crafting professions to 2 per char.

So in course of choosing, I got to the following question:

Are there any BOP item from crafting? Or maybe some other perks.

I've already read, that the legendary weapons require an ingridient from 2 different crafting professions - and that they may be BOP: has this been confirmed by now, or can I trade them at least across the same account?

Answer (score 1):

So two things:

First, every character can learn *every* crafting discipline. You won't even lose progress. The catch is that you can only have two *active* discipline at once (as in, can craft things with them), and it costs money to switch between them, based on how highly skilled a discipline you're switching *into*. (If you switch in to a discipline you have no experience in, it's free!)

Second, most untradable items are, in fact, account bound, so you can freely store them in your bank and remove them. I assume the actual Legendary Weapons will bind to a character, but the materials can be passed around willy nilly.

But Crafting in Guildwars 2 is very much its own part of the game. Crafted gear is equal to gear earned from any other number of options, and is not inherently better. The only real "perk", if you want to call it that, comes from convenience.

Comment: Can all crafting professions make bags? From what I've seen, only a few can.

Comment: @SaintWacko All the armor-producing professions can: Tailoring, Leatherworking, and Armorsmithing.